# Готовый QR Web Scanner на Flash

Tags: веб-программирование, flash, сниппет, qr

Приветствую, интересует, есть ли готовый flash сканнер кодов qr через веб-камеру? Исходник или готовый вариант? Для прикрутки к сайту.

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот попробуй. У меня сейчас камеры нет, поэтому проверить не могу.

[Flash-Webcam QR Snapshot](http://miniqr.com/reader.php)